# Characters matrix written in a binary file

Tags: c, matrix, character

I have a text file from which I read words. After that, I have to write in a binary file each word and near it the row and column where it appears. At _strdup(p) my programm crashes. Does anyone know why? I would appreciate your help. Here is the code:

```
void create(const char *filename, const char ****matrix) {

    FILE *u, *f;
    u = fopen(filename, "wb");
    assert(u != NULL);
    f = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    assert(f != NULL);
    (*matrix) = (char ***)malloc(sizeof(char **) * 1);
    int i = 0;
    int j=0; char buff[1024];
    while (fgets(buff, 1024, f)!=NULL) {

        (*matrix) = realloc((*matrix), (i + 1) * sizeof(char **));
        char *p = strtok(buff, " ().,");
        (*matrix)[i] = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
        while (p) {

                (*matrix)[i] = (char **)realloc((*matrix)[i], sizeof(char *)*(j + 1));
                strcpy((*matrix)[i], buff);
                (*matrix)[i][j] = _strdup(p);

                fwrite((*matrix)[i][j], sizeof(char *), 1, u);
                fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, u);
                fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, u);
                j++;

                (*matrix)[i][j] = NULL;

            p = strtok(NULL, " ().,");
        }
        (*matrix)[i] = NULL;
        i++;
        printf("\n");

    }
    fclose(u);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing pointer values to a file (at `fwrite((*matrix)[i][j], sizeof(char *), 1, u);`)?

Comment: You probably need to set `j = 0;` inside the outer `while` loop, before the start of the inner `while` loop.

Comment: `(*matrix)[i][j] = NULL;` and `(*matrix)[i] = NULL;` leak memory.

Comment: Just before the string duplicate call, you have allocated memory of `sizeof(char *)*(j + 1));`, where `j` is 0. So, 1 char. Surely you need to check how long your strings are?

Comment: @doctorlove I think that is just extending the array of char pointers by 1. The allocation for the string is done by the `_strdup` call and the returned pointer is stored in the newly created space.

Comment: @IanAbbott the pointer stores my word from the text that I want to show

Comment: @IanAbbott is there another way to write it in the binary file? Sorry I ask such this question but I'm totally beginner at binary files.

Comment: Provide example of your input file.

Comment: "is there another way to write it in the binary file?" You probably need to write the actual string contents rather than a pointer to the string contents, because the pointer will be meaningless and invalid for whatever program reads back the binary file. You'll need to take account of the fact that strings are variable length, so you will either need to write the null terminator after the string, or write a string length before writing the string. (Writing the length first may be more useful for whatever reads the string back from the file so it knows how much memory to allocate.)

Comment: @ryyker  Afiseaza pe ecran continutul fisierului de intrare,
mai putin primele m si ultimele n linii (1p). Valorile m si n si numele fisierului de

Comment: V-ați oprit comentariul în mijlocul propoziției și nu mi-ați adresat solicitarea. Puteți edita postarea dvs. cu câteva linii de conținut pentru un fișier de intrare normal? (De asemenea, folosiți engleza în orice comentarii.)

Comment: See additional responses to your questions in comments under my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The call to `_strdup` is likely failing because memory for `(*matrix)[i][j]` has not been allocated properly..

Using as many pointers as you are to read words from a file is not necessary, but given that you *are* using them, memory needs to be created for each, in the right order.

That is

```
matrix = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

is the first of locations required before creating any others

For example, the method to create a properly allocated collection of pointers, for a *4 dimension array*, might look like this:

```
char **** Create4D(int hR, int p, int c, int r)     
{
    char ****arr;
    int    w,x,y;

    arr = calloc(hR, sizeof(char *));
    for(w=0;w<hR;w++)
    {
        arr[w] = calloc(p, sizeof(char *));
        for(x=0;x<p;x++)
        {
            arr[w][x] = calloc(c, sizeof(char *));
            for(y=0;y<c;y++)
            {                                        
                arr[w][x][y] = calloc(r, 1); 
                                      // ^ sizeof(char) == 1
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Note the italicized is to remind you that this is not actually creating a *matrix*, just a collection of memory addresses, some with space for pointers, others with space for strings of `char`.

To call this function:

```
char ****matrix = Create4D(2, 4, 6, 8);
if(matrix)//always test for success.  If failed, matrix is set to NULL.
{ 
    //use matrix
    //With these arguments, 48 (2*4*6) pointers are created, 
    //each with space allocated to contain strings of 8 char each
    ....
```

Note also that in all of these calls, casting the return of [m][c]alloc is not used here, *[because it is not recommended in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)*.  Also, if you plan create all of this memory, corresponding calls to `free()` must be made for each call to `calloc()`.

Memory from calling the method above on my system is illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: ok, I've got the memory thing, but I have a question: why at the first calloc instead of  arr = calloc(hR, sizeof(char *)); you did't do  arr = calloc(hR, sizeof(char ***)); and the following ones with sizeof(char **), (char *) ?

Comment: Because the size of memory being created is `== sizeof (char *)`.  That is a 32bit memory location for a `char ***` is the same as that for a `char *` and the same for a `char ******`.  They are all 4 bytes.  If using 64bit addressing, then the size for each of them would be 8 bytes.  You can easily prove this by simply executing `int size = sizeof(char *);` then `int size2 = sizeof(char ******);`.  `size` and `size2` will be the same value.  They are just pointers.  The first is a pointer to a `char` sized memory location, the address for which takes 4 bytes, the second is a ...

Comment: ... pointer to a bunch of other pointers, i.e. `char *****`, still only requires 4 bytes, as does `char ****`, and `char ***`, and so on.   Keep in mind using more than 2 pointers (eg. `char **var` is rarely if ever needed to read and parse a file.  But when they ***are*** used it is for the purpose of creating addressable locations to _simulate_ array like indexing, as illustrated in the answer, where  In the example above, there are 2 blocks, each with 4 rows, each of those with 6 columns.  All 48 of those are memory locations pointing to indexable space enough for 8 char.

Comment: okk, but if I've got a matrix of strings like in my programm, I don't know the right dimensions, right? I could I know how much memory I should storage , without giving random numbers at malloc?

Comment: @Andre  - I typically read through the file first (using `fopen`, `fgets`, `strtok`, `fclose`, etc., to determine things like longest line and number of lines, or word count, longest word, depending on what I need in that program.  Then use those values to create a 2D matrix with number of strings, and length of longest string as the arguments (like the example code I provided, except with only 2 arguments)